# What to do with unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I did a search to find unanswered questions on website and found about [141 questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano%20duplicate%3Ano) which have no answers and are still open, these are the questions which seem to be on-topic on site because they are not closed as off-topic or duplicate.

How can users be encouraged to take a look at these questions and answer them, or review them to find out whether there duplicates of them available on website? Should some of these questions reviewed to find out whether they are eligible to remain opened?

In my opinion, some of these questions are good ones, however some other may not be so good to remain opened.

Answer (score 2):

> How can users be encouraged to take a look at these questions

There's already an ["Unanswered" tab](https://academia.stackexchange.com/unanswered) that directs some attention to these.

If you think a question is especially interesting, you can offer a bounty to get it more attention.

> Should some of these questions reviewed to find out whether they are eligible to remain opened?

I don't think unanswered questions deserve *extra* scrutiny.

"Abandoned" questions are already [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) as follows:

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0, **or** a score of 1 in case of deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

A systematic effort to close old questions in **large numbers** would probably be disruptive, since new questions would take longer to close.

I don't think such a systematic effort is necessary, but anyone undertaking it anyways should rate limit so as to avoid disruption.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the number of unanswered questions that on Academia.SE is actually a problem.  The current percent answered is 98%, which is quite healthy for an SE site ([see the site rankings by percent answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered)).  If the percentage starts climbing, it would be worth thinking about what to do, but at least for the few months I've been here these numbers have been pretty steady, so I don't think there is any harm in letting them be handled (or not) by the natural dynamics of the site.